# NGINX location rewrite for Gitlab

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I'm trying to make Gitlab work behind Nginx. my configs:

Nginx:

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
    server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket fail_timeout=0;
}
```

```
location /gitlab/ {
       rewrite ^/gitlab(/.*)$ $1 break;
       client_max_body_size 0;
       gzip off;
       proxy_read_timeout      300;
       proxy_connect_timeout   300;
       proxy_redirect          off;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
       proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
       proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
}
```

/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

```
external_url "https://myhostname.com/gitlab"
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
gitlab_workhorse['enable'] = true
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "unix"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket"
```

at request to myhost.com/gitlab/users/sign_in I get "/users/sign_in" not found

if I change in gitlab configuration

```
external_url "https://myhostname.com/"
```

(without `/gitlab` path in the end) it starts to work but it's always redirects to the / of the server instead of /gitlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already configured GitLab to use an URI prefix `/gitlab` with the

```
external_url "https://myhostname.com/gitlab"
```

(which is the only proper way to host anything bigger that a SPA under an URI prefix), you don't need to strip that `/gitlab` prefix from the request URI before passing the request to the GitLab backend. Remove that `rewrite ^/gitlab(/.*)$ $1 break;` line from your nginx config. What made you think it is needed at all?

Comment: apparently gitlab does not support relative urls

Comment: What makes you think so? The documentation [states](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configure-a-relative-url-for-gitlab) exactly the opposite. Did you test your enviroment without the `rewrite` directive using the `external_url "https://myhostname.com/gitlab"`?

Comment: yeah thank you it actually helped!